# Why two different instances of same class count as one when testing flows

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing

I am testing my MVI-built view model.

According to tested method we make a callback to api and return flow. The fake flow created for test:

```
class FakeSendCreditLimitClaimUseCase: SendCreditLimitClaimUseCase {

    override suspend fun invoke(
        accessToken: String?,
        agreementNumber: String,
        newCreditLimit: String,
        totalIncome: String
    ): Flow<RepositoryState<CreditLimitChangeClaim>> {
        return flowOf(
            RepositoryState.Loading(),
            RepositoryState.Complete(
                CreditLimitChangeClaim(
                    status = "NEW",
                    createDate = "12 sept 1993",
                    title = "Claim is created",
                    text = "You will get info in 7 days",
                    agreementNumber = "123456",
                )
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Here is the tested method of my ViewModel (deleted some methods to make it readable and added some methods from parent class):

```
@HiltViewModel
class IncreaseLimitViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val sendCreditLimitClaimUseCase: SendCreditLimitClaimUseCase,
) : BaseViewModel<IncreaseLimitState, IncreaseLimitActions, IncreaseLimitEffect>() {

    override val uiState: StateFlow<IncreaseLimitState>
        get() = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    private val _effect: Channel<IncreaseLimitEffect> = Channel()
    val effect = _effect.receiveAsFlow()

    override suspend fun handleAction(event: IncreaseLimitActions) {
        when (event) {
            is SendClaimAction -> {
                makeSendClaimRequest(event)
            }         
        }
    }

    override fun sendEffect(effect: Effect) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _effect.send(effect)
        }


    private suspend fun makeSendClaimRequest(event: SendClaimAction) {
        val accessToken = sessionRepository.getAccessToken() ?: return
        sendCreditLimitClaimUseCase.invoke(
            accessToken = accessToken,
            agreementNumber = event.agreementNumber,
            newCreditLimit = event.newCreditLimit,
            totalIncome = event.totalIncome
        ).collect { repositoryState ->
            when (repositoryState) {
                is RepositoryState.Loading -> {
                    sendEffect(SetLoadingVisibility(true))
                }
                is RepositoryState.Error -> {
                    sendEffect(SetLoadingVisibility(false))
                    sendEffect(NavigateToStatusScreen(null))
                }
                is RepositoryState.Complete -> {
                    sendEffect(SetLoadingVisibility(false))
                    sendEffect(NavigateToStatusScreen(claimData = repositoryState.data))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So according to this code in `makeSendClaimRequest` method I expect that there will be three sequential stated of this flow:
`SetLoadingVisibility(true)` -> `SetLoadingVisibility(false)` -> `NavigateToStatusScreen(claimData = repositoryState.data)`

because first I receive `RepositoryState.Loading` as first value of the flow and then `RepositoryState.Complete`.

The problem is that actually I

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Sending claim")
fun sendClaimTest2() = runTest(UnconfinedTestDispatcher()) {
    viewModel.sendAction(IncreaseLimitActions.SendClaimAction("123", "10000", "30000"))

    val firstItem =  viewModel.effect.first()
    println("${firstItem}") 
    // It is what I expect: SetLoadingVisibility(visible=true)
    assert(firstItem is IncreaseLimitEffect.SetLoadingVisibility && firstItem.visible)

    val secondItem = viewModel.effect.drop(1).first()
    println("${secondItem}")
    // It is what I don't expect: NavigateToStatusScreen(....)
    assert(secondItem is IncreaseLimitEffect.SetLoadingVisibility && !secondItem.visible)
    // No third item of the flow received
}
```

Please help me to understand why I send two sequential instances of effect: SetLoadingVisibility(true) and SetLoadingVisibility(false) and then instance of NavigateToStatusScreen(...), but can't see it when testing.

Comment: Try removing the `drop(1)` - the first call to `first()` may be consuming the first emitted event, since you're working with a flow not a static list.

Comment: I don't know if this is the reason, but in `sendEffect()` you use `launch()` and because of that you don't have any guarantees on the ordering of `send()` calls.